# Animated tab bar. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I want to make custom tab bar. And I'm using framework of [KittenYang](https://github.com/KittenYang/GooeyTabbar)

Here is everything is very beautiful, animated but I don't know how to add View Controller for showing. Thanks for any helps)

Comment: download the project in github , you get the sample project

Comment: Yeah I know, but here is just animation, without buttons and so on. I don't know how to add items to tab bar

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add an integrated `ViewController`class to your project, what you need to do instead is to add `TabbarMenu` class instance to your desired `UIViewController` subclass and add it as a subview to `UIViewController`'s view.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no proper (or even non-proper) documentation included, so you'll have to look deeper into implementation to figure out how to properly add `AnimatedButton` class instance to the `TabbarMenu` =\